# How to reduce the space between the title of the article and the contents

Tags: spacing, titles

I'm writing something with the `article` class and trying to reduce the space between the title of the article and the contents, as shown below. I know that I could insert `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}` or something right after the `\maketitle` command, but ***is there any way to handle the spacing by redefining the `\maketitle` command and inserting such a redefinition in the preamble?***

[image]

## MWE

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{space}{xeCJK}
%
\documentclass[
  a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
  \setmonofont[Scale = MatchLowercase]{zcoN}
  \setmathfont[]{Libertinus Math}
  \ifXeTeX
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[Scale = 1,BoldFont = SourceHanSansJP-Bold.otf]{SourceHanSerifJP-Light.otf}
  \fi
  \ifLuaTeX
    \usepackage[]{luatexja-fontspec}
    \setmainjfont[Scale = 1,BoldFont = SourceHanSansJP-Bold.otf]{SourceHanSerifJP-Light.otf}
  \fi
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Hoge Fuga1,},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[left = 20truemm,right = 20truemm,top = 20truemm,headsep = 5truemm,bottom = 30truemm,footskip = 15truemm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\usepackage[style=apa6,sortcites = true,sorting = nyt,backend = biber,maxcitenames = 2,style = authoryear-comp,language = auto]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{doc-creation/bibs/English.bib}

\title{Research Plan of the Doctoral Dissertation}
\author{Hoge Fuga\textsuperscript{1,*}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textsuperscript{1} The University of FooBar

\textsuperscript{*} Correspondence: \href{mailto:}{Hoge Fuga \textless{}\texttt{fuga@somewhere.com} (ID)\textgreater{}}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the `article` document class, the `\maketitle` command eventually calls the `\@maketitle` macro, which is defined as follows in `article.cls`

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

I will assume that you are mostly bothered by the two `\vskip 1.5em` instructions. If that's the case, you can get modify them either by redefining `\@maketitle` from scratch (via a suitable `\renewcommand` instruction) or by loading the `etoolbox` package and patching the *existing* command as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip 1.5em}{\vskip 1em}{}{} % modify 1st instance of '\vskip 1.5em'
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip 1.5em}{}{}{} % get rid of 2nd instance of '\vskip 1.5em'
\makeatother
```

Comment: In order to *really* smash the vertical whitespace between the title field and the subsequent material, I suppose you could change the second `\patchcmd` above to `\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip 1.5em}{\vskip -1em}{}{}`. However, I wouldn't go that far.